# If $z$ lies on the circle $|z-1|=1$ then$\frac {z-2} z$ is a purely imaginary number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ lies on the circle $|z-1|=1$ then $\frac {z-2} z$ is a purely imaginary number. This is what by book states. Did'nt understand why. Can someone help?

Actually I was thinking of a more geometrical approach to the problem, as pointed out by @did and the answer below. I also remembered the method that if $\bar z = -z$ then $z$ is purely imaginary. But can it also be done by visual geometry? Ok, I drew a circle centred at $1$ with radius $1$. The statement given implies $\frac {z-2} z$ equals any point on the semicircle. After that how do we prove its imaginary from there?

Comment: $$z=1+e^{it}\implies\frac{z-2}z=\frac{e^{it}-1}{e^{it}+1}=\cdots$$

Comment: Consider an $x+yj$ that satisfies $|z-1|=1$ - then work out $\frac{z-2}{z}$ - that's it

Comment: @Did while right, it's unlikely the OP understands the $re^{j\theta}$ form. Should anyone answer please bear this in mind.

Comment: @AlecTeal dont worry..i do

Comment: @AlecTeal Difficult to say since the OP posts only PSQs (but some of them were already about complex numbers, so we'll see...). // Later on: "dont worry..i do" OK, we saw...

Comment: What is the down vote for?How can I improve the question?

Comment: By putting *anything* personal in the pot. As you are probably well aware...

Comment: @Did Updated.Check please?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta I've tried to answer it on geometrical lines.

Comment: @Shailesh accepted !

Comment: @SanchayanDutta  Thanks.  It always helps to think of complex numbers and the various operations geometrically to the extent possible.

Comment: (Up to a change of variable, but I'd say it's close enough).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [complex numbers : If z lies on the circle $|z-1|=1,$ then the value of $\frac{z-2}{z}$ is ...........](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570247/complex-numbers-if-z-lies-on-the-circle-z-1-1-then-the-value-of-fracz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it geometrically. Let's call A as (2,0) and O as (0,0). Let the point z be P. Then consider $\frac{z-2}{z} = \frac{2-z}{0-z}$. The argument represents the angle between PA and PO.  Now because $|(z-1)| = 1$, P($z$) lies on the circle with A and O as the diameter. Hence the argument in question is a right angle. I have purposely put $\frac{z-2}{z} = \frac{2-z}{0-z}$ in a more recognizable form, given in general texts as $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2- z_1}$

Answer (score 4):

We have $| z-1| = 1$, ie

$$
\begin{align}
&(z-1)(\bar{z}-1) = 1 \\
\\
\implies &z\bar{z} - z - \bar{z} = 0 \\ 
\\
\implies &z(\bar{z}-2) = \bar{z}(2-z) \\
\\
\implies &\overline{\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)} = -\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)
\end{align}
$$

i.e. $\frac{z-2}{z}$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Verrry nice... +1.

Comment: Don't use  `\mid` for the absolute value (the spacing is wrong). Just write `|` or if you are pedantic: `\lvert .. \rvert`

Comment: You're welcome. `\mid` is for set-builder notation: $\{ x \mid x > 0 \}$.

Comment: Simply brilliant +1. Like your answer better than mine

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = x + iy$. Then $|z - 1|^2 = 1 \rightarrow (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Then show that the real part of $\frac{z-2}{z}$ is $x(x - 2) + y^2$, which is zero, from above.